# Why does removing gwibber-service get rid of indicator-me

Tags: 10.10, indicator, gwibber

I don't use gwibber at all but when I go to remove gwibber-service it wants to remove indicator-me.  I still use empathy so I like the indicator being in place. Is there any way to have this removed and why does it want to remove this?

--indicator-me is the indicator where you can change your online availability and access Ubuntu one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package [indicator-me](http://packages.ubuntu.com/indicator-me) depends on the package [libgwibber0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libgwibber0) which depends on the package [gwibber-service](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gwibber-service).  You can't remove [gwibber-service](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gwibber-service) without removing [libgwibber0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libgwibber0) and [indicator-me](http://packages.ubuntu.com/indicator-me).

You can, however, remove `gwibber-service` from your startup applications (System->Preferences->Startup Applications) so that it doesn't sit there using resources. You will find that the broadcast text box disappears when `gwibber-service` isn't running.

Comment: In the second part, if you talk about the Broadcast section in the messaging menu, that one is still there for me, even though gwibber-service is not running...

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9197/why-does-removing-gwibber-service-get-rid-of-indicator-me/9201#9201), the indicator-me package depends on libgwibber0 which depends on gwibber-service.

The reason that `indicator-me` has a dependency on `libgwibber0` is because `indicator-me` uses `libgwibber0` to provide the inline “social broadcast” posting input box.

The reason why `libgwibber0` has a dependency on `gwibber-service` is that `libgwibber0` is an library for interacting with `gwibber-service` - since it doesn't do anything without a running `gwibber-service`, the package correctly states the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Tracking the apt dependencies backwards is harder than it should be (or harder than I know). Looking at the (excerpted) output there seems an odd dependency:

```
$ dpkg -I libgwibber0_0.0.6-0ubuntu1_i386.deb 
 Package: libgwibber0
 Source: libgwibber
 Version: 0.0.6-0ubuntu1
 Depends: ... gwibber-service (>= 2.31.1)
 Homepage: https://launchpad.net/gwibber
 Description: Gwibber - shared library
  libgwibber provides a library for accessing social networks via
  gwibber.
  .
  This package contains shared libraries to be used by applications.
```

The odd dependency is that a library used by a service doesn't seem like it should depend on that service to be present. But I am not a package expert

If you don't have the .deb file hanging around,

```
sudo apt-get  install --download-only --reinstall libgwibber0
```

is a convenient way to populate /var/cache/apt/archvies/libgwibber0* without doing anything else.

Rather than kill the package (which could have bad effect for other users) just tell Gnome that you don't want it to run for you

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gwibber/preferences/autostart --type bool false
```