# How do I prevent gwibber-service from starting automatically?

Tags: 11.10, gwibber, autostart

I'm searching for a way to prevent gwibber-service from starting, but I can find none under Oneiric.

For a start, I confirmed that "Start service at login" was still unchecked in Gwibber preferences (it is), but gwibber-service still starts automatically at each login. So, I cross-checked under "Startup Applications..." (there is no entry for Gwibber there), I searched to see if there's an upstart job for gwibber-service (there is none), and I looked for a gwibber-service script in /etc/X11/Xsession.d (there is none).

So, I'm out of ideas. Do you know how to prevent gwibber-service from starting, or do you know other places where to look?

For further context, I had the "Start service at login" option already unckecked before upgrading to Oneiric. It used to work under Natty, but it no longer does.

Comment: There was a similar question once http://askubuntu.com/questions/9197/why-does-removing-gwibber-service-get-rid-of-indicator-me

Comment: @falstaff The old question is irrelevant for at least two reasons: there is no longer a Gwibber entry under startup applications and I don't want to uninstall gwibber-service, just to disable it from automatically running.

Comment: @falstaff I see the reference to Oneiric has been removed from my question title. I updated the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe disabling using gconftool helps?

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gwibber/preferences/autostart --type bool false
```

Comment: I just checked: it is already disabled (and I believe it is the setting controlled by the checkbox in the preferences UI).

Comment: The question I posted above concludes that indicator-me package is using this service, so it might be a problem of that starting the service although disabled...

Comment: There might be a problem with the condition from gconf, move the autostart file from `/etc/xdg/autostart` to another directory, e.g.
`sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/gwibber.desktop ~`

Comment: Didn't know about /etc/xdg/autostart... sigh... I see the file has a line reading `AutostartCondition=GSettings org.gwibber.preferences autostart`, but the setting is ignored anyway. I should probably file a bug, and I'll remove the desktop file as a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, will try that, to see if it helps - does it works the same way to disable BEAM service?!?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by disabling it in Startup Applications. Before going to Startup Applications make sure you made visible hidden applications with this:

sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop